# left join same table twice slow query

Tags: sql, left-join

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT xx_coinType AS yy_type, xx_sell AS sell_xx
           FROM xxs
           ORDER BY xx_id DESC) AS xxs
               ON xxs.yy_type = zz.zz_coin
LEFT JOIN (SELECT xx_coinType AS yy_type, xx_sell AS old_sell_xx
           FROM xxs
           WHERE xx_time < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR))
           ORDER BY xx_id DESC) AS old_xxs
               ON old_xxs.coin_type = zz.zz_coin
```

So I have 2 left joins in my query which select from same table but with a where on one. Since its the same table I select from the query is super slow. How can I fix this?

Comment: "since its the same table I select from the query is super slow" - I don't know what "joining the same table" and "query is super slow" has to do with each other - maybe you have no index on the joining columns?

Comment: `ORDER BY` in Derived Tables`?  Weird...

Comment: You could CTE the table you join and join the CTE.

Comment: Firsty just remove the **ORDER BY xx_id DESC**. You don't need reordering in fact

Comment: id is primay key, removing either one will make it a normal speed (0.02sec) with both of them its 12,2 sec So that was why I thought it was about left joining same table twice

Comment: Tag dbms, different products optimize in different ways!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, no need to use the `order by` clause in derived tables.
Second, your first derived table simply selects all the records in the table, so I don't see the point of it.

Try this:

```
LEFT JOIN xxs
               ON xxs.yy_type = zz.zz_coin
LEFT JOIN (SELECT xx_coinType AS yy_type, xx_sell AS old_sell_xx
           FROM xxs
           WHERE xx_time < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR))
           ) AS old_xxs
               ON old_xxs.coin_type = zz.zz_coin
```

Or this:

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT xx_coinType AS yy_type, xx_sell AS sell_xx
           FROM xxs
           WHERE xx_time >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 24 
           ) AS xxs
               ON xxs.yy_type = zz.zz_coin
LEFT JOIN (SELECT xx_coinType AS yy_type, xx_sell AS old_sell_xx
           FROM xxs
           WHERE xx_time < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR))
           ) AS old_xxs
               ON old_xxs.coin_type = zz.zz_coin
```